# How do we stop rate limiting Brute Force attack on login form

Tags: c#, security, model-view-controller

How do we stop rate limiting Brute Force attack on login form, Right now I created one Msite application which is runs on Intranet as well Internet And I want to prevent this from brute force login attack, Please help Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO, best way no doubt is Captcha, but if you like to explore more bit the you can apply some security checks for that.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to prevent a bruteforce attack is captcha, it is annoying but it is the most efficient way. Here you have [Microsoft's approach](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-make-and-use-d0d1752a).

Other less intrusive options you have are password length, password complexity, limit login attempts, modifying .htaccess file, two factor authentication.

You should balance the inconvinience / security requirements to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for writing to me but my client says he don't want captcha so what should I do.

Comment: Use all the other mentioned together, if it is not enough secure for you still, you can use Cloudflare.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach to make brute-force attacks more difficult, is to ensure that a log-in attempt (successful or unsuccessful) takes a bit of time.

As a trivial example: If a single attempt takes one millisecond, an attacker can try out a dictionary with ten thousand of the most frequent passwords in just ten seconds. If you ensure that a single attempt takes at least one second, they would need something like three hours.

Of course you need to find a balance, you do not want to inconvenience your legitimate users. But typically they only need one attempt, so a delay of e.g. a second should be hardly noticeable. And you could - and probably should - make you implementation more sophisticated, e.g. increase the delay after unsuccessful log-in attempts, limit per client-IP, etc.